# How to import data into Neo4j from Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: azure, neo4j, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to import data into Neo4j from Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: So you want to import .csv files from Azure blob ?

Comment: Depends on what kind of data

Comment: @StanleyGong Yes. I could probably do it using python py2neo. Is there any other way?

Comment: @RB17, I am not sure why you are looking for other ways to import .csv data, may I know your requirement or any  issue while you use py2neo to import data?

Comment: @StanleyGong I just wanted to see if there is a way to use Azure Data factory or some non-python options to load Neo4j from Azure Blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it done by using python azure-blob-storage and py2neo libraries. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any free tools.

On the commercial side, [GraphAware Hume Orchestra](https://graphaware.com/products/hume/) has Azure BlobStorage connectors

[image]

[image]

There is also the possibility to create your own protocol for Neo4j LOAD CSV (for eg s3, azure etc,) .

I have written an example here : https://github.com/ikwattro/neo4j-load-csv-s3-protocol

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview - creates a URL with a signature that allows you to access files directly over `https`. You can then `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "<url>" AS row CREATE...`, etc... This has the benefit of not requiring any additional software, custom code, etc...
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-how-to-mount-container-linux - can be used to mount an Azure storage container to a folder in your Neo4j instance (e.g. `/var/lib/neo4j/import/myazurecontainer`). This folder can then be used to access files in blob storage as if they're local.

I'd be hesitant to install an orchestration framework (e.g. GraphAware's Hume Orchestra) or ETL tool if you *only* want to load some data from Azure Storage.